# RedirectPermanent vs RewriteRule [R]

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have a perm_redirects.conf file that gets included into my apache config stack where I have lines in the format

```
RedirectPermanent /old/url/path /new/url/path
```

It looks like I'm required to use an absolute URL for the new path, e.g.:  `http://example.com/new/url/path`. In the logs I'm getting *"incomplete redirect target /new/url/path was corrected to http://example.com/new/url/path."* (paraphrased).

In the 2.2 docs for `RewriteRule`, at the bottom they show the following as being a valid redirect, with only the url-paths instead of an abs URL for the right hand side of the redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^/old/url/path(.*) /new/url/path$1 [R]
```

But I can't seem to get that format to work to replicate the functionality of the `RedirectPermanent` version. Is this possible?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^old/url/path(.*)$ new/url/path$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

WFM:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit 
RewriteRule ^/old/url/path(.*) /new/url/path$1 [R]
```

Result:

```
wget http://localhost/old/url/path/foo
--2010-08-09 15:41:20--  http://localhost/old/url/path/foo
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://localhost/new/url/path/foo [following]
--2010-08-09 15:41:20--  http://localhost/new/url/path/foo
```

Note (1) you probably want [R=permanent]. The default is a temp redirect. (2) You do not want just the [L] as that will result in an internal redirect invisible to the end user (not caused by the L, the default action "" is an internal redirect). RedirectPermanent generates a 3xx response to the end user. You could add the L, i.e., [R=permanent,L] to stop mod_rewrite from processing any more rules.